# The value for "webpart context configureStart" must not be undefined

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

Getting following error in after adding webpart. I can add it `workbench.html` but in `workbench.aspx` it's not working.

> The value for "webpart context configureStart" must not be undefined

[image]

It's happening in all samples from [sp-dev-fx-webparts](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts). It's also happening in fresh installation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So apparently we messed up in the shift away from @microsoft/sp-client-preview towards @microsoft/sp-webpart-base .  While we fix up documentation, samples, yeoman, etc.  please follow the instructions in the "New BaseClientSideWebPart package location" section of this page - https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Release-Notes-Drop-5